# Salesforce - soql System.QueryException Try Catch Issues

Tags: apex, soql, community, try-catch

I am building dynamic soql query from an object. I am getting the object in a Field and another field from a object in Salesforce for the Query. With that said I am trying to capture the Query Exception but when the Query Exception happens the code just stops and an error appears on the screen without hitting my catch...... I tried searching for a solution but I do not see one..... Anythoughts outside of quering to see if the value from the field is really an object?

Even If i put my catch above my return statement that i read somewhere it still bypasses it....

```
Public List<sObject> getsObjectId(String pstrObjectName, String pstrName, List<sObject> plstOrder){
    Try{
    String strQuery = 'Select Id  From ' + pstrObjectName + ' where Name =  \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(pstrName) + '\'';
    plstM2MOrder = Database.query(strQuery);

    return plstOrder;

    }Catch(DMLException  e){
    system.debug('exception happened' + e.getmessage() );
    clsErrorhandling.InsertLogError(e.getMessage(), strErrorHandlingObjRecord, 'trgOrder');
    Return Null;
    }            

}
```

Comment: Just a highly opiniated comment from my side - in your error handling catch block you're cutting off a lot of possibly useful information, e.g the exception type and the exception stack trace. You're only keeping the exception message.
I would probably also return an empty List<SObject> instead of null of you want the caller to proceed the same as if not results were found in case of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think a `QueryException` is a `DMLException`; also catch and handle `QueryException`.

Comment: Thanks --- I didnt Catch that...

Answer (score 4):

Adding on top of Keith's answer.

You are using `Database.query()`, which is not a DML operation. A [`DMLException`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) is thrown only on scenarios as mentioned below, and thus your operation for any issues on SOQL never reaches the catch block.

> Any problem with a DML statement, such as an insert statement missing a required field on a record.

For any SOQL operations you will need to catch the `QueryException`:

> Any problem with SOQL queries, such as assigning a query that returns no records or more than one record to a singleton sObject variable.

In your case specifically though, `Database.query()` will only throw a [*Runtime Exception*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) if the query does not return the correct sObject type. In all other cases, the exception block will never be reached.